# With Adobe Acrobat how do I replace all instances of one font with another font throughout the pdf document?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I need to carry out a global font substitution in Adobe Acrobat.

In particular, I would like to know, with Adobe Acrobat how do I replace all instances of one font with another font throughout the pdf document? I need to do this because font X which I am substituting and which was used within the document is unavailable so I cannot select it and I need to make changes to text that was inserted using that font in a uniform manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should try it out Acrobat DC, and see if you can do it in the Edit Text and Images tool.

Otherwise, you definitely should be able to do this using PitStop by Enfocus, a plug-in for Acrobat being used (among others) for last second edits in the prepress world.